# Is there a way to remove or replace njada's hide helmet in Skyrim without mods?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want her to wear a circlet or some headset that doesn't hide her hair. Is there a way to do this though the console without installing a mod? I tried to remove the helmet through the console, but it only works temporarily as the hide helmet gets respawn after you leave her.

Comment: It seems like even mods have trouble changing NPCs’ outfits permanently. But there might be a way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this myself and it worked for me:

1. Open the console, click on the NPC
2. type 'openactorcontainer 1' and put the cloth you want to equip from your inventory in there
3. type 'showinventory', there should be a list of items the npc has. Try to find the ID of the item you want to remove, 
   a line could look like this:

   Boots (001b1be) (100,100.00%) - Worn - Outfit

   in this case, '001b1be' is the id of the item
4. type 'removeitem [ITEM ID] 1, in this case: removeitem 001b1be 1
5. now search for the item id of the item you want to equip and type:

   'equipitem [ITEM ID] #', e.g.: equipitem 001b1be 1

   the 1 behind the ID means that the outfit cannot be removed

If the default outfit should be reequiped for whatever reason and its not permanently, you could create a textfile inside your skyrim installation folder and write in it:

```
prid [follow id]
equipitem [item id] 1
```

save it and type ingame: 'bat [name of the txt file]' whenever you want to overwrite the npcs default outfit. As far as i know, thats all you can do without using mods, but i hope this helps.

Comment: I can't remove the item, because it's not in the inventory.

Comment: nevermind, it seems to work.